# Using Google Map with out Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Weeks ago started a simple project that displays information of our local health centers and hospitals, i was able to fetch the list from a database unto a listview, when i started the project i did not select the GOOGLE API in min SDK version, now i want to add google map for each entry. Is it still possible to use google map without selecting the google api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to use the maps api. Its extremely easy to do. All you have to do is go into the project explorer in eclipse, right click on your project, go to preferences, select android, go down to whatever api it is your using and then check on the maps version right underneath. Youll also have to get a map key but thats super easy as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Google Maps without the Google API (ok, you could use a [webview widget and use the javascript API instead](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3), but I think you don't want this). But why don't you add the API right now?

Comment: I did not that it is still possible to add the API once you have started a project. How do i do that?

Comment: Thanks for the information sir, i've already editted my references